# com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, amazon-s3, inputstream

Getting exception while parsing input stream which is of XML type.

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected: dataLength=75876; expectedLength=481292147; includeSkipped=true; in.getClass()=class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$2; markedSupported=false; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=0; resetCount=0
    at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.checkLength(LengthCheckInputStream.java:151)
    at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:109)
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this exception? And how to resolve it.
Here I am having S3Object from which I am getting InputStream (data.getObjectContent()). InputStream contains xml data which I am parsing . While parsing I am getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing some other party is telling you the file size, and this file size is incorrect. So one obvious answer is to calculate the filesize in bytes yourself before you try streaming it to S3. i.e. set the filesize to

```
file.length()
```

If you post your code I might be able to help further.